# Use geometry nodes with a painted texture map, or a weight map, to control the thickness distribution of hair?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to use a weight map or a painted texture map to control the distribution of the thickness of hair strands in the old particle mode or in the new hair system mode.

I am trying to do this using the new geometry node system.

I have a torus that has hair attached to it. I can draw the vertex map on the torus object but I need to access it in geometry node modifier attached to the hair.

Ideally I could access the values of the `Group` vertex group of the `Torus` inside the `HairThickness` geometry node tree.

Unfortunately, the [Named Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/read/named_attribute.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.2#bpy-types-geometrynodeinputnamedattribute) gets the attribute only from the current geometry.

[image: Screenshot showing my work]

My algorithm that I have in mind is to take the position of the hair and find the corresponding mesh index of the Torus. After getting the mesh index I should be able to access the vertex weight value.

In the screenshot above I take the `mean` of the weight map of the `Torus` just for debugging purposes. What I would like to do is to take the position of the hair and find the corresponding mesh weight value of the `Torus`

How can I do this?

### Blender file

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: Yes I am doing that now. Here is the .blend file https://blend-exchange.com/b/XbJanYrM/